# Write program which count sum of numbers divided by 4

Tags: c#, division

I need to write a program which count sum of numbers divided by 4. I'm really beginner in C#. 
Could you lead me to solve this problem?

I write something like this but I don't know what next and there is one problem because I put only two numbers but numbers could be a lot of.

```
Console.WriteLine("number a");
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("number b");
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = a + b;
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Please add some more information on what you are trying to achieve. An example of input/output could help a lot.

Comment: It's only part of it but I don't want full code of this. I need only tips which lead me to solve this program

Comment: @marcomasini Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = sum / 4 ; 
Console.WriteLine ( "result is="+ result ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
double sum = Console.ReadLine().Split().Sum(x => int.Parse(x)) / 4.0;
```

Than you can enter any space separated array like

```
1 3 5 7
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.  Unfortunately it's exceed my level a little bit.  I can't define it like 'sum' because I did it earlier where is 'int sum = a + b;'